# MongoDB multiple group aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm struggling to get the output of an aggregation pipeline as I want it to be, I'm close but I'm not sure what I need to do in order to get what I want.

I have a database with bank statement records, which have a date, amount, balance side (debit/credit) and a category (shopping/car/etc..). I want to aggregate these records by grouping them by year/month/category in the following manner:

```
[{
    credit: <total sum of year>,
    debit: <total sum of year>,
    _id: <year>
    months: [{
        month: <month number>,
        credit: <total sum of month>,
        debit: <total sum of month>,
        categories: [{
            category: <category id>,
            credit: <total sum of category in that month>,
            debit: <total sum of category in that month>
        }]
    }]
}]
```

I currently have the following aggregation statement:

```
        [
        { $group: {
            _id: { maand: { $month: "$datum"}, jaar: { $year: "$datum"}}, //categorie: "$categorie", 
            debet: {
                $sum: {
                    $switch: {
                        "branches": [
                            { 
                                "case": {$eq: ["$zijde", "D"]},
                                "then": "$bedrag"
                            }
                        ],
                        "default": 0
                    }
                }
            },
            credit: {
                $sum: {
                    $switch: {
                        "branches": [
                            { 
                                "case": {$eq: ["$zijde", "C"]},
                                "then": "$bedrag"
                            }
                        ],
                        "default": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }},
        { $group: {
            _id: "$_id.jaar",
            debet: {$sum: "$debet"},
            credit: {$sum: "$credit"},
            maanden: {
                $push: {
                    maand: "$_id.maand",
                    debet: "$debet",
                    credit: "$credit"
                }
            }
        }}
    ],
```

Which produces what I want but does not include the categories yet. This is the output:

```
[{
    credit: ***,
    debit: ***,
    _id: <year>
    months: [{
        {
            credit: ***,
            debit: ***,
            month: <month number>
        }
    }]
}]
```

Now my question is, how do I mix in the categories in this aggregation to get the output that I want? I tried adding the categorie to the initial group statement but then the months array will contain an item for each month/category combination and not the summed total of that month anymore. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

---

**UPDATED CODE BASED ON ANSWER**

```
[
        { $group: {
            _id: { maand: { $month: "$datum"}, jaar: { $year: "$datum"}, categorie: "$categorie"}, //categorie: "$categorie", 
            debet: {
                $sum: {
                    $switch: {
                        "branches": [
                            { 
                                "case": {$eq: ["$zijde", "D"]},
                                "then": "$bedrag"
                            }
                        ],
                        "default": 0
                    }
                }
            },
            credit: {
                $sum: {
                    $switch: {
                        "branches": [
                            { 
                                "case": {$eq: ["$zijde", "C"]},
                                "then": "$bedrag"
                            }
                        ],
                        "default": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }},
        { $group: {
            _id: {maand: "$_id.maand", jaar: "$_id.jaar"},
            categories: { 
                $push: {
                    categorie: "$_id.categorie",
                    debet: "$debet",
                    credit: "$credit"
                }
            },
            debet: {$sum: "$debet"},
            credit: {$sum: "$credit"},
        }},
        { $group: {
            _id: "$_id.jaar",
            debet: {$sum: "$debet"},
            credit: {$sum: "$credit"},
            maanden: {
                $push: {
                    maand: "$_id.maand",
                    categories: "$categories",
                    debet: "$debet",
                    credit: "$credit"
                }
            }
        }}
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your
 actual fields are. But you have to use three `$group` stages to achieve that output. Something like

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "month": { "$month": "date" }, "year": { "$year": "date" }, "category": "$category" },
    "credit": { "$sum": "$credit" }
    "debit": { "$sum": "$debit" }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "month": { "$month": "$_id.month" }, "year": { "$year": "_id.year" }},
    "categories": {
      "$push": { "category": "$category", "credit": "$credit", "debit": "$debit" }
    },
    "credit": { "$sum": "$credit" }
    "debit": { "$sum": "$debit" }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.year",
    "months": {
      "$push": { "categories": "$categories", "credit": "$credit" "debit": "$debit" }
    }
    "credit": { "$sum": "$credit" }
    "debit": { "$sum": "$debit" }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! With a few minor adjustments this gives the expected result, I put the updated query in the question.